# Facebook Event - guest list & posting settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to add a "create Facebook event" functionality to my application that uses Graph API. I have read their documentation and I am able to create an event with basic informations, like name, description, time, place etc.

However, the documentation doesn't mention two fields I'm especially interested in: **Show the guest list on the event page**  and **Non-admins can write on the wall**.

I have investigated the data sent to Facebook while creating new event on site and it seems like these two fields are named respectively **guest_list** and **connections_can_post**. Unfortunately, adding these two fields to my request has no effect. I have tried different combinations, but they seem to be ignored.

Is it possible to set those two fields through API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe either of those fields can currently be set via the API